# Multiple div popups

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I have a JavaScript to open a DIV as popup.
But now I want to open several different popups from different DIVS and I can't get it to work properly.

I use the following JavaScript:

```
<script>
window.onload = function()
{
    var show = document.getElementById('show-div');
    var hide = document.getElementById('hide-div');
    var popup = document.getElementById('popup-div');

    show.onclick = function(e)
    {
        popup.style.visibility = 'visible';
        return false;
    }

    hide.onclick = function(e)
    {
        popup.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

and for the div I use the followin code:

```
<a id="show-div" href="#">link</a>
<div id="popup-div">
<div id="popup-header">
<div id="popup-title">...Popup title...</div>
<a id="hide-div" href="#">X</a></div>
<div id="popup-body">
<p>This is the content of the div....</p>
</div>
</div>
```

This works for 1 link but even when I use a different DIV ID's (and associated var element like "var popup1 = document.getElementById('popup-div1');" and popup1 onclick events)  I can't get it work properly.
How can I make it work with several links with all it's own DIV with content.

(as I can't answer my own question, here is how I fixed it)
I made it work with the following code:

```
<script>
window.onload = function()
{
    var show = document.getElementById('show-div');
    var show2 = document.getElementById('show-div2');
    var hide = document.getElementById('hide-div');
    var hide2 = document.getElementById('hide-div2');
    var popup = document.getElementById('popup-div');
    var popup2 = document.getElementById('popup-div2');

    show.onclick = function(e)
    {
        popup.style.visibility = 'visible';
        return false;
    }

    show2.onclick = function(e)
    {
        popup2.style.visibility = 'visible';
        return false;
    }

    hide.onclick = function(e)
    {
        popup.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        return false;
    }
    hide2.onclick = function(e)
    {
        popup2.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

and

```
<a id="show-div" href="#">link</a>
<div id="popup-div">
<div id="popup-header">
<div id="popup-title">...Popup title...</div>
<a id="hide-div" href="#">X</a></div>
<div id="popup-body">
<p>This is the content of the div....</p>
</div>
</div>
<a id="show-div2" href="#">link2</a>
<div id="popup-div2">
<div id="popup-header">
<div id="popup-title">...Popup title2...</div>
<a id="hide-div2" href="#">X</a></div>
<div id="popup-body">
<p>This is the content of the div2....</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try using class for event handlers.

Comment: what do you mean it doesnt work properly? do you have a css that is related to popup-div and it cannot find popup-div1? please paste your multiple div-links code and tell us what you expect to happen. thnx

Comment: make use of "this" inside the javascript to get the currently clicked link and correspondingly associate it with the corresponding div popups.

Comment: make use of http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals. for your simplicity

Comment: I had corresponding css code which made the div hidden. But due to the variables in the javascript the second link didn't generate a popup

Answer (score 0):

I believe following is that you want....

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KqLYD/2/)

**JS Code:**

```
var show = document.getElementById('show-div');
var hides = document.getElementsByClassName('hide-div');
var popups = document.getElementsByClassName("popup-div");

show.onclick = function (e) {
    for (var i = 0; i < popups.length; i++) {
        popups[i].style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
    return false;
}

for (var j = 0; j < hides.length; j++) {
    hides[j].onclick = function (e) {
        this.parentNode.parentNode.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        return false;
    }
}
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<a id="show-div" href="#">Show/Hide</a>

<div id="popup-div" class="popup-div">
    <div id="popup-header">
        <div id="popup-title">...Popup title...</div>
<a id="hide-div" class="hide-div" href="#">X</a>

    </div>
    <div id="popup-body">
        <p>This is the content of the div....</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="popup-div" class="popup-div">
    <div id="popup-header">
        <div id="popup-title">...Popup title...</div>
<a id="hide-div" class="hide-div" href="#">X</a>

    </div>
    <div id="popup-body">
        <p>This is the content of the div....</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tested this but it didn't work. But I got a way to fix it anyway. I will place it as answer

Comment: I used the code I placed in my question to fix it. The above code didn't generate a popup

Comment: ok..i thought there is only one show link is required to show all of the popups..anyway you got a fix..:)